# Convert list into index and range of 0-1.0

Tags: python

Edit: I have updated the graphic to try and explain what I am aiming for.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: The diagram really doesn't help. 4 lines starting with `list=` are kinda confusing.

Comment: I have updated the graphic, I hope its a bit more clear.

Comment: ... why the heck do you use a graphic containing nothing but text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this...

```
In [24]: value = [17, 18, 19, 0, 1]

In [25]: valueIndex = range(len(value))

In [26]: valueIndex
Out[26]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# Get the valueRemapped in float format
In [27]: valueRemapped = [float(x)/valueIndex[-1] if x > 0 else x for x in valueIndex]

In [28]: valueRemapped
Out[28]: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

# Zip the two lists
In [29]: tempresult = zip(value, valueRemapped)

In [30]: tempresult
Out[30]: [(17, 0), (18, 0.25), (19, 0.5), (0, 0.75), (1, 1.0)]

# Sort the lists based on value list
In [31]: tempresult.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))

In [32]: tempresult
Out[32]: [(0, 0.75), (1, 1.0), (17, 0), (18, 0.25), (19, 0.5)]

# print the corresponding data
In [33]: [x[1] for x in tempresult]
Out[33]: [0.75, 1.0, 0, 0.25, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 4):

`new_list = range(len(old_list))`

Comment: Nice, this approach is a lot faster than using enumerate in a list comprehension.

Comment: `new_list = list(range(len(old_list)))` in Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Note: Since list is a keyword you shouldn't name your variable list.  `enumerate(oldlist)` is a generator that yields tuples of indexes and list elements from oldlist.  This list comprehension will yield all values of the index and store them in `newlist`.  If you need the element as well as the index, this is a good approach.  The range(len(thelist)) approach suggested is much faster though if you had a lot of larger lists.

```
newlist = [i for i,_ in enumerate(oldlist)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the graphic with what I aim to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: lst = [17,18,19,0,1]

In [12]: p = [i/(len(lst)-1.) for i in range(len(lst))]  # [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

In [13]: [p[i] for i in sorted(range(len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)]
Out[13]: [0.75, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what I think the questions is:

```
value = [17, 18, 19, 0, 1]  
value_index = range(len(value))
value_remapped = map( lambda x : float(x) / 4.0, value_index)
paired = zip(value, value_remapped)
paired_sort = sorted(paired)


value_sort, value_remapped_sort = zip(*paired_sort)

print "value=", value
print "value_remapped=", value_remapped
print "paired=", paired
print "paired_sort=", paired_sort
print "value_sort=", value_sort
print "value_remapped_sort=", value_remapped_sort
```

Which gives:

```
value= [17, 18, 19, 0, 1]
value_remapped= [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
paired= [(17, 0.0), (18, 0.25), (19, 0.5), (0, 0.75), (1, 1.0)]
paired_sort= [(0, 0.75), (1, 1.0), (17, 0.0), (18, 0.25), (19, 0.5)]
value_sort= (0, 1, 17, 18, 19)
value_remapped_sort= (0.75, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5)
```